# focus() method scrolls top only in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, focus

In every browser `focus()` method on `input` scrolls to top of the page. I hack it with custom method like this:

```
$.fn.focusNo = function () {
    var x = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollLeft,
        y = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollTop;

    this.focus();
    window.scrollTo(x, y);
};
```

but in Interner Explorer (9, 10) this solution doesn't work..

**How do you solve this problem?**

Comment: Modify your question so that it can be useful to others

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong, the `focus` method does not scroll to the top of the page, it scrolls to make the focused element visible in the page. It's likely that there is something else that is casing the scroll to the top. How are you calling the code?

Comment: @Guffa calling as usual jquery code ``$(function () { ... });``

Comment: @Kosmetika: Are you using the code directly in the `ready` event? Then the page would normally already be scrolled to the top. Are you calling the code from any event handler?

Comment: @Guffa yes.. i described what is the problem already..

Comment: @Kosmetika: Yes, you described what you think is the problem, but the `focus` method simply doesn't do what you descibe, so there has to be something else that does that.

Comment: I think you can use the specific ie function setActive to focus without scrolling

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use jquery instead.

```
$(document).scrollTop(x);
$(document).scrollLeft(y);
```

Comment: Then please check your x and y values are being populated properly.

Comment: they are populated properly

Comment: This solution works properly for me in IE9. I am using jquery 1.8.3

Answer (score 1):

IE dosen't have `scrollTo`  instead it was having `doScroll`.
Further, IE 9 and on-wards has deprecated  `doScroll`, instead use property `scrollLeft` or `scrollTop`.
Link to IE [Scroll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536414(v=vs.85).aspx)